# Drag and Select ListBox Items?

Tags: wpf

how to select items in listbox, if start dragging from one item to the end of the dragging?

Comment: This doesn't work for you by default?

Comment: You mean like `Box Selection` in `Windows Explorer`?

Comment: simply (say) if i drag from element 5 to 10 , i want to mark these items as selected?

Comment: You can hold Shift and Select. Make the listBox `SelectionMode="Extended"` without that, you have to manually select the items by getting the hit test on each item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this approach on a question on msdn but I can't find it again so I can't link it.. Anyway, this works pretty good, only problem being when dragging and scrolling at the same time, then it can miss a few items. I've created a custom control library called MultiSelectLibrary which you can use like this

Add a reference to MultiSelectLibrary which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?t6wfxgb2xn9erkj) (Source [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?mw64b77pxae8cj7))
Add the namespace and the MultiSelectListBox with SelectionMode="Extended" and it should work.

```
xmlns:mslb="clr-namespace:MultiSelectLibrary.MultiSelectListBox;assembly=MultiSelectLibrary"

<mslb:MultiSelectListBox SelectionMode="Extended" .../>
```

If you rather just use some code behind you can do it like this (doing the same thing as the library)

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Extended"
         ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseUp"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

And in code behind

```
private object _anchor, _lead;
private Boolean _inMouseSelectionMode;
private List<object> _selectedItems = new List<object>();

private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _selectedItems.Clear();
    _inMouseSelectionMode = false;
    _anchor = null;
    _lead = null;
}

private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        return;

    _anchor = sender;
    _inMouseSelectionMode = true;
    _selectedItems.Clear();
    _selectedItems.Add(sender);
}
private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_inMouseSelectionMode)
        return;

    if (_lead != sender)
    {
        var last = _lead;
        _lead = sender;

        if (_selectedItems.Contains(_lead))
            _selectedItems.Remove(last);
        else
            _selectedItems.Add(_lead);
    }

    foreach (var item in _selectedItems)
        ((ListBoxItem)item).IsSelected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Meleak, will dive into the code as I want something alike.

Comment: How can I draw a frame on what I select?

Comment: @Anders Rune Jensen: You're right, not sure what happend. I'll look into it!

Comment: @@Anders Rune Jensen: Seems to be a problem with MediaFire at the moment.. I uploaded it again and updated the link, lets see if it helps

Comment: There's a problem with this.  If you drag too quickly, you have gaps in the selection!